# Texture paint - can paint in UV editor but on on the mesh in 3D view port

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, texture-painting

- I am struggling with texture paint mode.

  - I have terrain model mesh (50K polygons)
  - I followed several tutotorials more times on 2 different PCs, but the problem is I can paint only in paint view in UV editor but I can`t paint directly on the mesh in 3D view port in texture paint mode.

When I paint in UV editor, it is displayed on UV image and also on the model/mesh but when I pay in 3D viewport on the mesh nothing happens at all in both views (3D viewport/UV editor) :(

- I have flipped normals already
- I have image selected in CANVAS in "slots" tab in texture paint mode
- I unwrapped the model in UV editor (edit mode in 3D viewport, selected all faces, pressed U --> Unwrap or Smart UV unwrap)
- I created new image in UV editor, saved it and, reloaded it before painting, I can see it on the model when I turn on texture paint mode.
- I created textures in general properties (N) where I loaded images.

  - I have blender render mode on
  - I have multitexture settings on in general properties
  - I have "space" selected in brush/stroke options

Obviously I miss something or doing something wrong. Please help, I am really desperate :(

I went through all videos and forums on the net but nothing helped yet.

Thank you ! :) [image]